# I can't detect collision infront of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basically if there's collision infront of the player it shouldn't go forward anymore, but the player goes forward no matter what.

```
if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0 &&
        !(Physics.Raycast(PlayerObject.transform.position,
                          Vector3.forward,
                          PlayerObject.collider.collider.bounds.size.z * 1.05f)))
    {
        PlayerObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you're performing a `Raycast` using physics, so anything not enabled for physics won't show up. You're also using `Vector3.Forward` instead of `PlayerObject.transform.forward`, so you're getting the global forward `(0,0,1)` instead of the player's actual vector. Furthermore, but using the player's position, it won't notice, say, a low or high-hanging wall.

Note there is also the built-in [`CharacterController`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) component to handle this sort of behaviour, as well as intelligently handling Ramps and Steps.